# Access-Control-Allow-Origin when sending request to google api

Tags: angularjs, google-api

Im trying to send an request in my angularjs application to google API to get the attractions in a radius around an location. But I get this error message in chrome:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

I've tried both json and jsonp but the result is the same. :S

```
    $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&type=museum&key=<MYKEY>')
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.dataResult = response.data;
        });
    $scope.getlocation = function() {

        $scope.method = 'GET';
        $http({ method: $scope.method, url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&type=museum&key=<MYKEY>&callback=JSON_CALLBACK" }).
        success(function(data, status) {

            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
            console.log(data);
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
        });

    };
```

I dont want to show result on a map, I only want it in list format.

Comment: The problem is your origin is `http` and you destination is `https`. Make those both equal.

Answer (score 0):

This is CORS issue, from the client-side you can enable cors requests like this.

```
angular.module('yourapp').config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

The problem with your case is , `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=51.503186,-0.126446&radius=5000&type=museum&key=<MYKEY>` does not allow your origin to have access to the response. Therefore you are not able read it.

I hope you have a valid key and also while registering you have listed your localhost in the place of domain... as google needs to know these.

Comment: I've enabled http://localhost, http://localhost:9000/#/ and http://localhost:9000 to the keys. And if I check the Google Places API Web Service I see request increasing with every request. And also the service api is enabled.

Comment: @JediSchmedi: can you just add the above thing in your config and check whether its working or not.

Comment: this is app.js

    .config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;        
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

Comment: Can you try one of the examples here in a fiddle and share... https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors#example-1-using-the-request-header